# What does the <<support>> stereotype in UML represent?

Tags: uml

There's a `<<support>>` stereotype however there appears to be no information about its use case. For example can I use it to mean that a service such as the help desk "supports" an application.

Comment: It could be a custom stereotype, see http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/standard_uml_models/creatingcustomstereotypes.html

Comment: @VS1 - It is straight out of the box so unless Sparx has created it, it may be a custom stereotype.

Comment: are you talking about using `<<support>>` as use-case/class stereotype itself? or stereotype for an association?

Comment: @user2511414 - I am looking at it from a use-case and class stereotype as well as an association.

Comment: it looks okay for association(s) but I haven't seen it for use-cases, the same thing called `<<auxiliary>>` is used in Class-diagram, but for use-case you would just look at a little different then you will find it as either `<<include>>` or `<<extends>>`

Comment: @user2511414 - Thanks. What does the association mean though? Does it mean that an element such as a actor supports a given node? How does this differ from `<<auxiliary>>`?

Comment: as I said `<<auxiliary>>` is used in class-diagram->classes, not for associations. and about the association: with association we specify the relation between members/components in diagrams, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557012/uml-class-diagram-fitness-tracker/19561328#19561328) `aggregation` or `composition`, or `dependency`, generally they are called `associations`. stereotypes would assigned to classes/components, members(field/method), and associations. here the `<<support>>` association is acceptable for associations, not for use-cases.

Comment: @user2511414 - Thanks. I understand that `<<supports>>` is acceptable for associations however its usage is not clear. Can you give me a real world example of how I can use `<<supports>>`?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I tried to provide two example, check the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really a little hard(at least for me) to provide an example about `<<support>>` stereotype, or equivalent.
but the first thing I'm thinking about is-> consider a distributed application.
 here the core system will process client's business with a base processing system, so beside the base system, this is possible that during the process some process(hand) get joint to the system, in other word some extra process unit(APU/GPU/CPU/Co-Processor), in fact there is an `Extra_Process`(s) which **supports** the base process module. so I think(not sure) the following diagram would describe it.
[image]
The another possible(not sure) example(for class-diagram) would be-> consider a n-tier application which each base(mother) modules has a global `ThreadPool` in order to limit and manage the max running of threads, so suppose that whenever a module is idle/not-busy it could give threads to the another module which is busy/need-help, so here in fact a module is supporting another module somehow.
[image]
And correctly, I really cannot provide any example for use-case diagram(not-enough-coffee), but the important thing is, stereotypes are like comments, you would just remove then and use notes instead, or description withing document or code comments, but this is a good practice to use them correctly.
I hope I could give some hand(time for coffee, really).

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at UML 2.5 and 2.4.1 specifications and it does not seem to be an official stereotype...
Which tool do you use? which version of UML does it implement?

Regards,

RB

Comment: The tool being used is Sparx Enterprise Architect and it is implementing the latest version of UML. It comes straight out of the box so I don't think it is a custom stereotype.

Comment: It seems to be ... Take a look at the tolls documentation because I do not find it in the UML 2.5 specification.

Comment: http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/standard_uml_models/standardelementstereotypes_2.html does not include it.